# Java adding methods

Tags: java, class, methods

Hello guys i am quite new to java and i have found some logic error. First of all i am trying to add methods to my class but it doesn't seem to be working. When i run and i put 0 it does not show error but it print out another "enter your choice", then when i typed 0 it showed invalid input. Another error is that how can i proceed to my next step?

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

 public class OnlineOrder {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String item;
    int choice = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    String choiceFood = "";
    float price = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    readChoice();
    checkChoice(choice);
    processOrder(choiceFood, price, quantity);
    System.out.println("Enter quantitiy of ");

    while (choice <= 1 || choice >= 4) {
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            choiceFood = "Hamburger";
            price = 1.50f;
            break;

        case 2:
            choiceFood = "Cheeseburger";
            price = 2.50f;
            break;

        case 3:
            choiceFood = "French Fries";
            price = 2.00f;
            break;

        case 4:
            choiceFood = "Soft Drinks";
            price = 1.95f;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            sc.close();
            break;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Are you a student? (Yes/No) : ");
    String input = sc.next();
    char ynStudent = input.charAt(0);
    double discount = 0;
    if (ynStudent == 'y' || ynStudent == 'Y') {
        discount = 0.9;
    }
    float totalPrice = price * quantity;
    totalPrice = (float) (totalPrice * discount);

    System.out.println("You have ordered " + quantity + " " + choiceFood);
    System.out.print("You have to pay total of $");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", totalPrice);
}

public static int readChoice() {
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Item                             Price");
    System.out.println("====                             ===== ");
    System.out.println("1. Hamburger                     1.50");
    System.out.println("2. Cheeseburger                  2.50");
    System.out.println("3. French Fries                  2.00");
    System.out.println("4. Soft Drinks                   1.95");
    System.out.println("Enter your choice(1,2,3 or 4): ");
    choice = sc.nextInt();

    return choice;
}

public static String processOrder(String choiceFood, double price, int choice) {

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        choiceFood = "Hamburger";
        price = 1.50f;
        break;

    case 2:
        choiceFood = "Cheeseburger";
        price = 2.50f;
        break;

    case 3:
        choiceFood = "French Fries";
        price = 2.00f;
        break;

    case 4:
        choiceFood = "Soft Drinks";
        price = 1.95f;
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        break;

    }

    return choiceFood;
}

public static int checkChoice(int choice) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your choice (1,2,3 or 4:): ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");

        }
    } while (choice >= 1 || choice <= 4);

    return choice;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hint: changing the value of a parameter in a method doesn't change anything else.

Comment: i am sorry i have to create 2 methods. One of which is to readChoice() to get the choice from user and return a valid choice to the calling program, and another method is to get a String from user and return the String to the calling program

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't change anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program you wrote have some bugs.

You are not assigning choice variable with the return value from readChoice() method.

```
choice = readChoice();
```

instead of `readChoice();`

Also change checkChoice() method as follows to make sure it shows message for all invalid choices like 0

```
public static int checkChoice(int choice) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");

}else{
        return choice;
}
do {
    System.out.println("Enter your choice (1,2,3 or 4:): ");
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");

    }
} while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);

return choice;
```

}

Assuming you want to ask the user to enter a choice until he enters a valid choice.

Also again reassign the value from checkChoice() to variable choice.

```
choice = checkChoice(choice);
```

Comment: ohhh alright but i will have syntax error as there is no int in the parameter choice= checkChoice();

Comment: edited. It seems you don't have much understanding about basics of java. Please have a basic understanding and then try to write the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OnlineOrder {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String item;
    int choice = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    String choiceFood = "";
    float price = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    readChoice();
    choice = checkChoice();
    processOrder(choiceFood, price, quantity);
    System.out.println("Enter quantitiy of ");


        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                choiceFood = "Hamburger";
                price = 1.50f;
                break;

            case 2:
                choiceFood = "Cheeseburger";
                price = 2.50f;
                break;

            case 3:
                choiceFood = "French Fries";
                price = 2.00f;
                break;

            case 4:
                choiceFood = "Soft Drinks";
                price = 1.95f;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid");
                sc.close();
                break;


    }

    System.out.println("Are you a student? (Yes/No) : ");
    String input = sc.next();
    char ynStudent = input.charAt(0);
    double discount = 0;
    if (ynStudent == 'y' || ynStudent == 'Y') {
        discount = 0.9;
    }
    float totalPrice = price * quantity;
    totalPrice = (float) (totalPrice * discount);

    System.out.println("You have ordered " + quantity + " " + choiceFood);
    System.out.print("You have to pay total of $");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", totalPrice);
}

public static void readChoice() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Item                             Price");
    System.out.println("====                             ===== ");
    System.out.println("1. Hamburger                     1.50");
    System.out.println("2. Cheeseburger                  2.50");
    System.out.println("3. French Fries                  2.00");
    System.out.println("4. Soft Drinks                   1.95");


}

public static String processOrder(String choiceFood, double price, int choice) {

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            choiceFood = "Hamburger";
            price = 1.50f;
            break;

        case 2:
            choiceFood = "Cheeseburger";
            price = 2.50f;
            break;

        case 3:
            choiceFood = "French Fries";
            price = 2.00f;
            break;

        case 4:
            choiceFood = "Soft Drinks";
            price = 1.95f;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            break;

    }

    return choiceFood;
}

public static int checkChoice() {
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (choice >= 1 || choice <= 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter your choice (1,2,3 or 4:): ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } ;

    return choice;
}
```

}

Hope this works for you. By the way you are not asking for quantiy of items anywhere in the code.

Comment: rename readChoice() to showChoice() and checkChoice(0 to validate choice.

Comment: Just dumping his reworked homework will not teach him anything. No explanations, no nothing. That is **not** helpful.

Comment: @GhostCat he can compare the code and findout what was wrong with the earlier code.

Comment: i would not copy if i don't understand. But thank you

Answer (score -1):

When you enter 0 and you enter a while, you don't have a case condition
You can only use defult so it's not valid